# SQLiteException: no such table: Images (Sqlite code 1):while compiling: select * from Images, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am using an external Database that I created in another Android App and I tried to import it to my actual project. I created the ASSETS FOLDER and pasted the Database in it but it didn't work. I added the Read and Write Storage permissions but it doesn't work too.

Here is my SQLite. class

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database and Table version

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyImages.sqlite";
public static final String DBLOCATION = "/data/data/bayram.com.historyimages/databases/";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Images";

//Columns
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "Image";
public static final String COLUMN_YEAR = "Year";
public static final String COLUMN_KEYWORD = "Keyword";
public static final String COLUMN_PLACE = "Place";
public static final String COLUMN_RESUME="Resume";
//Database version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database creation sql statement
// + COLUMN_IMAGE+ " BLOB NOT NULL,"
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_NAME + "( "
        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + COLUMN_IMAGE+" BLOB,"
        + COLUMN_YEAR+ " TEXT,"
        +COLUMN_KEYWORD+ " TEXT,"
        +COLUMN_PLACE+ " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_RESUME+ " TEXT);";
Context mContext;
String databasePath;
String databaseFile;


public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    //,String databasePath, String databaseFile)

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.mContext=context;
    //this.databasePath=databasePath;mContext.getFilesDir().getPath();
    //this.databaseFile = databaseFile;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    //Toast.makeText(mContext,"Data Base created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public boolean insertImageWithInfos(ImageInfos imageInfos) throws SQLException {


    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
    // contentValues.put(COLUMN_ID,imageInfos.getId());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_IMAGE, imageInfos.getImage());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_KEYWORD,imageInfos.getKeyword());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_YEAR,imageInfos.getYear());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_PLACE,imageInfos.getPlace());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_RESUME,imageInfos.getResume());
    long i= sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null,contentValues);
    if (i==-1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Elements are not inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Elements are inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;

    }



}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion>oldVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllImages() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    //hp = new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from "+TABLE_NAME, null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
/*public void showDbElements(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){

    }
}
*/
SQLiteDatabase db;


public ArrayList<ImageInfos> getValuesFromDataBase() {
    ArrayList<ImageInfos> imageInfosArrayList = new ArrayList<ImageInfos>();
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Log.i("MySQLiteHelper","openDatabase is Successful");
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())

        {
            Log.e("moveToCursor: ", "Cursor.moveToFirst is true");

            while(cursor.isAfterLast()==false)
            {
                ImageInfos imageInfos=new ImageInfos(mContext);
                imageInfos.setImage();
                imageInfos.setYear(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_YEAR)));
                imageInfos.setKeyword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_KEYWORD)));
                imageInfos.setPlace(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PLACE)));
                imageInfos.setResume(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_RESUME)));
                imageInfosArrayList.add(imageInfos);
                cursor.moveToNext();


            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        Log.e("database elements: ", String.valueOf(imageInfosArrayList.size()));

        return imageInfosArrayList;

    }catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

     // SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);



}
public Bitmap getImage(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();


    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select "+COLUMN_IMAGE+" from "+TABLE_NAME, new String[]{});
    if (cursor==null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Cursor is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    byte[] blob=cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_IMAGE));
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    return bitmap;
}
}
```

and here is The Fragment where I should display my table elements

```
public class UmgebungFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "UmgebungFragment";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

ArrayList<ImageInfos> imageInfosArrayList;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private Context mContext;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Images.db";

public UmgebungFragment() {

}


public static UmgebungFragment newInstance(String param1) {
    UmgebungFragment fragment = new UmgebungFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1,null);


    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext=getContext();
    dbHelper=new MySQLiteHelper(mContext);
    imageInfosArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(MySQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
        String outFileName = MySQLiteHelper.DBLOCATION + MySQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.w("Umgebung","DB copied");

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


    imageInfosArrayList=dbHelper.getValuesFromDataBase();



    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);


    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_umgebung, container, false);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_umgebung);

   // imageInfosArrayList=dbHelper.getValuesFromDataBase();





    if (imageInfosArrayList!=null)
    {
        recyclerAdapter= new RecyclerAdapter(mContext,imageInfosArrayList);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        return view;
    }else{
        Log.i(mContext.toString(),"imageInfosArrayList returned null");
    }

    return view;
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using this? https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper and we can't see your database schema, but why are you attempting to create a table after you copied from a file?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by creatin a new table? what I am trying to o is to access the table that exsts in my database

Comment: Have you tried moving `dbHelper=new MySQLiteHelper(mContext);` and `dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();`,  to after the database copy from the assets? I guess that cricket_007 didn't see that `db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);` is commented out, but in principal I think creating the database (be it with our without a table) and then copying the database file afterwards will be problematic, which is what I think cricket_007 was effectively saying. If issues persist then please include the logcat.

Comment: @MikeT thanks it is working!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that you are effectively creating a database before you copy the file from the assets. That is, the following lines from the fragmet's `onCreate`in method `dbHelper=new MySQLiteHelper(mContext);` and then `dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();` will create a database and invoke the helper's `onCreate` method. The result will be an empty database as the helper's `onCreate` method doesn't create a table.

Copying the file after will be problematic because the cached/in memory components will reflect a database with no tables even though the underlying file includes a table or tables. Even if the structure/schema did match i.e. tables matched you would likely have issues.

One fix would be to move the lines `dbHelper=new MySQLiteHelper(mContext);` and `dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();`, to be after the copy so that you open the copied database rather than another database.

e.g.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext=getContext();
    // Line (1st) moved from here
    imageInfosArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    // Line (2nd) moved from here
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(MySQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
        String outFileName = MySQLiteHelper.DBLOCATION + MySQLiteHelper.DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.w("Umgebung","DB copied");

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    dbHelper=new MySQLiteHelper(mContext); //<< Line (1st) moved here
    dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();        //<< Line (2nd) moved here
    imageInfosArrayList=dbHelper.getValuesFromDataBase();
```